# In matlab in a product dense matrix * sparse matrix, how can I only calculate specific entries?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, product, sparse-matrix

We have a matlab program in which we want to calculate the following expression:

```
sum(  (M*x) .* x)
```

Here, `M` is a small dense matrix (say 100 by 100) and `x` is a sparse fat matrix (say of size 100 by 1 000 000, with 5% non-zero entries). When I run the code, then first `M*x` is calculated, which is a dense matrix-- however, most of the computation that went into computing that matrix is a complete waste of time, as most of it will be zero-ed out in the point-wise product with `x` afterwards.

In other words: What I want to do is to only calculate those entries `(i,j)` of `M*x` which correspond to `(i,j)` for which `x(i,j)` is non-zero. In the end, I will then also only be interested in each column count.

It seems pretty simple to start with but I could not figure out how to tell matlab to do it or how to reshape the calculation so that matlab does it efficiently. I would really like to avoid having to code up a mex-file for this operation, and this operation is eating up most of the computation time.

Here is a code snippet for comparison:

```
m = 100;
n = 100000;
density = 0.05;

M = randn(m); M = M * M';
x = sprandn(m,n,density);

tic
for i = 1:100
     xsi  = sum((M * x).*x,1);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 13.570713 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute `(M*x) .* x`: find which entries of the final result can be nonzero (using `find`), compute manually only for those (`sum(M(...).'.*x(...)) .* nonzeros(x).'`), and from that build the final matrix (using `sparse`):

```
[ii jj] = find(x);
R = sparse(ii, jj, sum(M(ii,:).'.*x(:,jj)) .* nonzeros(x).');
```

Of course, to compute `sum((M*x) .* x)` you then simply use

```
full(sum(R))
```